# How to reshard the collection with another key after shard in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am facing with resharding in mongodb. I tried to drop database, collection.

Then:

```
sh.enableSharding("database-name")
sh.shardCollection("database-name.collectionName", {key: 1})
```

But I got the error:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "collection database-name.collectioName already sharded with 5 chunks.",
    "code" : 23
}
```

I did search everywhere but not found the answer. Please give me advice.

Thanks,
Dien